# VS Codeでプログラムを作るときにESP32:Platform IOで#pragma region　#pragma endregion で警告を出ないようにしたい

Tags: c++, vscode, esp32

現在、Visual Studio CodeにPlatform IOを追加してESP32用のプログラムを作っています
普段Visual Studioでコーディングしていて
**#pragma region ここで説明**
**#pragma endregion ここで説明**
と言うように便利に使っていて、VS Codeでも使っているのですが
当たり前かもしれませんがコンパイラは警告を出してきます

コンパイルするときにこの二つを警告を出さないように出来ないでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問文からは使用しているコンパイラーがわかりませんでしたが、GCCやCLANGであればコンパイルオプション `-Wno-unknown-pragmas` を指定すれば警告されなくなります。

Answer (score 1):

#pragma regionを折り畳みのために使っているのであれば、ちょっと不細工かもしれませんが、

```
#ifdef __HOGE__
#pragma region ここで説明
#endif

#ifdef __HOGE__
#pragma endregion　ここで説明
#endif
```

みたいに#ifdef~#endifで存在しない__HOGE__を指定してやればコンパイラからは無視されますが、折り畳みは可能です。